# no such method error for cxf and websphere

Tags: java, cxf, websphere-8

I am getting the below exception.
I have deployed my war on Websphere 8.5.5 with
Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last).

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response.readEntity(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.servicegateway.client.GatewayRESTClient.getAcknowledgement(GatewayRESTClient.java:407)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.servicegateway.client.GatewayRESTClient.invoke(GatewayRESTClient.java:481)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.servicegateway.client.GatewayRESTClient.testConnection(GatewayRESTClient.java:380)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.webservice.ServiceGatewayMediatorImpl.testConnection(ServiceGatewayMediatorImpl.java:92)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mi.ui.servicegateway.gateway.bo.GatewayControllerHelper.pingTestForServiceGateway(GatewayControllerHelper.java:168)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mi.ui.servicegateway.gateway.bo.GatewayControllerHelper.getUIBeanList(GatewayControllerHelper.java:135)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mi.ui.servicegateway.gateway.bo.GatewayControllerHelper.fetch(GatewayControllerHelper.java:90)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mi.ui.servicegateway.gateway.ServiceGatewayListComposer.doAfterCompose(ServiceGatewayListComposer.java:67)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild0(UiEngineImpl.java:739)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:685)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:629)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreateChild(UiEngineImpl.java:661)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate0(UiEngineImpl.java:629)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execCreate(UiEngineImpl.java:596)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.createComponents(UiEngineImpl.java:926)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.AbstractExecution.createComponents(AbstractExecution.java:231)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions.createComponents(Executions.java:176)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.commonui.components.eQUIComponentUtils.createAndAttachPage(eQUIComponentUtils.java:475)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mi.ui.servicegateway.configuration.GatewayConfigurationComposer.onConfirmMenuChange(GatewayConfigurationComposer.java:103)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mi.ui.servicegateway.configuration.GatewayConfigurationComposer.access$000(GatewayConfigurationComposer.java:19)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.mi.ui.servicegateway.configuration.GatewayConfigurationComposer$1.onEvent(GatewayConfigurationComposer.java:87)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:206)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:140)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1602)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1386)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage0(UiEngineImpl.java:446)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execNewPage(UiEngineImpl.java:305)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.process(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:225)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet.doGet(DHtmlLayoutServlet.java:146)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.filter.security.SecureCookieFilter.doFilter(SecureCookieFilter.java:51)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.filter.security.CrossFrameScriptingFilter.doFilter(CrossFrameScriptingFilter.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at com.eqtechnologic.eqube.filter.security.eQUrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(eQUrlRewriteFilter.java:34)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javax/ws/rs/core/Response.readEntity()` is available since JAX-RS 2.0 (see [Response](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-) spec)

Probably you are compiling with JAX-RS 2.0 and running with JAX-RS1.0. Ensure JAX-RS 2.0 libraries are first loaded in classpath